# How to test mdb column types in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datacolumn

I have the following code

```
Dim dbMnt As OleDb.OleDbConnection
dbMnt = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\temp\data.mdb")
dbMnt.Open()

Dim qdfTabCols As DataTable = dbMnt.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, New Object(){Nothing, Nothing, "Table1")

Dim dr As DataRow
For Each dr In qdfTabCols
    Msgbox(dr("TABLE_NAME") & " " & dr("COLUMN_NAME") & " " & dr("DATA_TYPE"))
    'In here I would like to test the column data type
Next
```

Inside the "For Each" I would like to test for the various column data types and handle them differently.
I used to just use: dbText, dbMemo, dbDate.
How do you write this "If" statement in VB.net?

```
If (dr("DATA_TYPE") = ????) Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken , `DATA_TYPE` will contain [OleDbType Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx). Try This :

```
If (dr("DATA_TYPE") = OleDb.OleDbType.DBDate) Then
```